# Как добавить свой пункт в меню "Surround with" в Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: меню Surround with (CTRL + ALT + T)]

Изучаю программирование и бывает, что проверяешь правильно ли работает метод, который просто возвращает значение, а не выводит его в консоль. Я написал его вызов и приходится переписывать эту строку c `System.out.println(вызов_метода())`, чтобы увидеть значение.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы процесс переписывания строчки кода заменился на нажатие нескольких клавиш?

Comment: Нажать на Configure Live Templates... в этом меню и добавить свой шаблон по аналогии с уже существующими.

Comment: Шаблон добавить можно, но вот как сделать, чтобы он появлялся в этом меню? Если знаете как, тогда нужны более конкретные инструкции. 

Допустим в этой статье в официальной документации говорится, что "You can edit code templates that are used in the surround statements", но не показывается как или просто я не понял. (Хотя там написано, что можно редактировать, про создавать свои речи не идет :() 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html

Comment: В Live Templates нужно найти sout (System.out.println), в тексте шаблона заменить `$END$` на `$SELECTION$` (или `$SELECTION$$END$`), тогда этот шаблон будет появляться в списке  для оборачивания. `$SELECTION$` показывает место, куда подставится выделенный текст после подстановки, если эта переменная не указана, то видимо считается что шаблон не предназначен для оборачичания.